# I always have to access Jupyter Notebook as a root user

Tags: 18.04, jupyter

Every time, I use Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 18.04, I have to access `sudo bash` first and then type `jupyter notebook --allow-root` to use Jupyter Notebook without any problem. This is because when I use normal user to access jupyter notebook, I will always get this error. 
[image]

Every time I try to create new jupyter notebook workspace, I will get this error. I can't just type `$ jupyter notebook` to use Jupyter workspace and save my new creation.

Please, could you tell me how to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

This is what I see in `/home/sura/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret` using `sudo nano`

[image]

And this is what I see in `ls -l /home/sura/.local/share/jupyter`

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of `/home/sura/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret`? Run `ls -l /home/sura/.local/share/jupyter` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the path /home/sura/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret, but there is nothing in there. It's totally empty.

Comment: I have updated all the requirements you need to see, do you have any solution for my issue? It seems that Jupyter Notebook was set to be used as root.

Comment: It is far easier for people to help you if in future you just copy and paste output from commands into your answer and mark them as code using the '{}' button instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: I am so sorry. I will improve myself. By the way, do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Jupyter.

It seems that your Jupyter data files are owned by root and therefore your user may not write to them. This is most probably the case because you ran Jupyter as root.

To rectify, you need to change the ownership of the files to your user.

Run `sudo chown -R sura:sura /home/sura/.local/share/jupyter` and test if it works now. If it still does not work, check the error message. After the term "permission denied" is a path. Check the permissions of that path (`ls -l <path>`) and if the file or directory belongs to root, change then owner (`sudo chown -R sura:sura <path>`).

Afterwards, never run Jupyter as root, always as your user.

Comment: Hello, the solution you gave me causes another error. `Unexpected error while saving file: Documents/python/Untitled.ipynb [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/sura/Documents/python/.ipynb_checkpoints/Untitled-checkpoint.ipynb'` I don't know why this can happen, hahahaha

Comment: As stated, you need to repeat that process (check ownership and fix it) until you can save again. I suspect you have a bunch of files used by Jupyter and owned by root scattered all over your home directory. For this file you should check ownership of `/home/sura/Documents/python/` and `/home/sura/Documents/python/.ipynb_checkpoints` using `ls -l path`. If either belongs to root, run `sudo chown -R sura:sura` on it. If unsure you can just run `sudo chown -R sura:sura /home/sura/Documents/python` and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: Hello, I can fix this issue by using your way. I have used `sudo chown -R sura:sura /home/sura/Documents/python/.ipynb_checkpoints` at the end. Thank you very much

Comment: Now I can just type `$ jupyter notebook` in the terminal. And also I can use jupyter notebook as root.